# StyleCop SA1210 Ordering according to different cultures

Tags: coding-style, stylecop

In Czech language, alphabet differs from English by character `CH`. It is considered as standalone letter, whereas on English, there's no such letter.

This causes troubles when namespace starts on `D`, `C` and `CH` - especially when StyleCop is configured on build server, which has different locale than developers' machines.

(just note, Czech alphabet is: `A B C D E F G H CH I J K` ...)

According to SA1210, this is correct for `en-US`

```
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
```

... but for `cs-CZ` order should look like this:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
```

I found StyleCop configuration element:

```
<StringProperty Name="Culture">en-US</StringProperty>
```

... unfortunately it does not enforce correct ordering on developer machine with `cs-CZ` locale. (I'm getting StyleCop error either on developer machine or build server)

Is there any way how to force StyleCop checking ordering in given locale, no matter what system locale is?

Comment: This is an open issue - https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/issues/87